# How do I use typedef and typedef enum in C?

Tags: c, typedef

Consider:

```
#define MAXROW 20
#define MAXCOL 60
typedef State Grid[MAXROW+2] [MAXCOL+2]
typedef enum state {DEAD,ALIVE} State
```

How do I use `typedef` and `typedef enum` in C? What does this part of the code do?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The question is a bit too basic, and most likely has already been asked on SO. What material are you using to learn C? You should find a better material which answers that question, or else you will get bogged down too much by questions. Look for best C tutorials on Google and SO.

Comment: Actually i know basic C but that grid statement is what i am not clearly getting

Answer (score 119):

```
typedef enum state {DEAD,ALIVE} State;
|     | |                     | |   |^ terminating semicolon, required! 
|     | |   type specifier    | |   |
|     | |                     | ^^^^^  declarator (simple name)
|     | |                     |    
|     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
|     |
^^^^^^^-- storage class specifier (in this case typedef)
```

The `typedef` keyword is a pseudo-storage-class specifier. Syntactically, it is used in the same place where a storage class specifier like `extern` or `static` is used. It doesn't have anything to do with storage. It means that the declaration doesn't introduce the existence of **named objects**, but rather, it introduces names which are **type aliases**.

After the above declaration, the `State` identifier becomes an alias for the type `enum state {DEAD,ALIVE}`.  The declaration also provides that type itself. However that isn't `typedef` doing it. **Any** declaration in which `enum state {DEAD,ALIVE}` appears as a type specifier introduces that type into the scope:

```
enum state {DEAD, ALIVE} stateVariable;
```

If `enum state` has previously been introduced the `typedef` has to be written like this:

```
typedef enum state State;
```

otherwise the `enum` is being redefined, which is an error.

Like other declarations (except function parameter declarations), the `typedef` declaration can have multiple declarators, separated by a comma. Moreover, they can be derived declarators, not only simple names:

```
typedef unsigned long ulong, *ulongptr;
|     | |           | |  1 | |   2   |
|     | |           | |    | ^^^^^^^^^--- "pointer to" declarator
|     | |           | ^^^^^^------------- simple declarator
|     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------------------- specifier-qualifier list
^^^^^^^---------------------------------- storage class specifier
```

This `typedef` introduces two type names `ulong` and `ulongptr`, based on the `unsigned long` type given in the specifier-qualifier list. `ulong` is just a straight alias for that type. `ulongptr` is declared as a pointer to `unsigned long`, thanks to the `*` syntax, which in this role is a kind of type construction operator which deliberately mimics the unary `*` for pointer dereferencing used in expressions. In other words `ulongptr` is an alias for the "pointer to `unsigned long`" type.

Alias means that `ulongptr` **is not a distinct type** from `unsigned long *`. This is valid code, requiring no diagnostic:

```
unsigned long *p = 0;
ulongptr q = p;
```

The variables `q` and `p` have exactly the same type.

The aliasing of `typedef` isn't textual. For instance if `user_id_t` is a `typedef` name for the type `int`, we may not simply do this:

```
unsigned user_id_t uid;  // error! programmer hoped for "unsigned int uid".
```

This is an invalid type specifier list, combining `unsigned` with a typedef name. The above can be done using the C preprocessor:

```
#define user_id_t int
unsigned user_id_t uid;
```

whereby `user_id_t` is macro-expanded to the token `int` prior to syntax analysis and translation. While this may seem like an advantage, it is a false one; avoid this in new programs.

Among the disadvantages that it doesn't work well for derived types:

```
 #define silly_macro int *

 silly_macro not, what, you, think;
```

This declaration doesn't declare `what`, `you` and `think` as being of type "pointer to int" because the macro-expansion is:

```
 int * not, what, you, think;
```

The type specifier is `int`, and the declarators are `*not`, `what`, `you` and `think`. So `not` has the expected pointer type, but the remaining identifiers do not.

And that's probably 99% of everything about `typedef` and type aliasing in C.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `ulongptr q = p` for both p and q to have exactly same type?
The way you wrote, you can have `ulong *q = p` and that would have exactly same type as `unsigned long *p`

Comment: @Bhargav You are right, that is a typo. `ulongptr *q = p` requires a diagnostic; it's a conversion between dis-similar pointer types without a cast.

Comment: +2 for Godlike ASC art skillz.

Answer (score 28):

`typedef` defines a new data type. So you can have:

```
typedef char* my_string;
typedef struct{
  int member1;
  int member2;
} my_struct;
```

So now you can declare variables with these new data types

```
my_string s;
my_struct x;

s = "welcome";
x.member1 = 10;
```

For `enum`, things are a bit different - consider the following examples:

```
enum Ranks {FIRST, SECOND};
int main()
{
   int data = 20;
   if (data == FIRST)
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

using `typedef enum` creates an alias for a type:

```
typedef enum Ranks {FIRST, SECOND} Order;
int main()
{
   Order data = (Order)20;  // Must cast to defined type to prevent error

   if (data == FIRST)
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: in the second example,how does 20 and first or second get compared?

Comment: enum is a integer type; first value in the enum is 0 (unless otherwise specified) second is the first value+1 (0+1 in this case) and so on. When you declare a variable of type enum_data_type, you can only assign it values which exist in the enum....the compiler does the verification.

Comment: so in the 2nd example,if(data==FIRST) is false,will it be true if i assign int data=0?

Comment: that is correct; but by all means this is just an example of how to use it, if you really want to understand build a test project with this code and play around with it...

Comment: Oh by the way, you use enums because the provide a means of changing the values in the ENUM without having to change the code. So if at some point you decide to change the code like enum Ranks {FIRST=5, SECOND}...the code will still work. But take that into consideration when assigning values to the variables.

Comment: `typedef` doesn't define a new data type; it defines an identifier for an existing data type.

Comment: Using `typedef` with an enum does not affect the properties of the enum. Your second pair of examples: firstly it is a red herring, in the first one you could have written `enum Ranks data = 20;` instead of `int data = 20;`. But in both cases, it is permitted to assign `20` to a variable of the enum type, it is not an error.

Comment: You can also use it like that: **Order data = Order::FIRST;**

Comment: @Patapoom No you can not! It is C not C++. In C there is no such thing as Order::FIRST

Answer (score 1):

A *typedef*, is just an alias -

- "typedef is a reserved keyword in the programming languages C and C++. It is used **to create an additional name** (*alias*) for another data type, but does not create a new type" ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef))

- "the typedef declaration provides a way **to declare an identifier as a type alias**, to be *used to replace* a possibly complex type name" ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef))

Comment: Like here, where this "type_name" typedef is used for a "struct structure_name"  - https://www.codesdope.com/cpp-typedef/