# Typedef & enum in C format and advtantages

Tags: c

I’m trying to figure out how to use typedef enum properly. What exactly can I do with the following, how would I call values from typedef enum, and can I link one of the values in typedef enum to a number in an Array? Thanks

```
typedef enum
{
  A1 = 10,
  A2 = 20,
  A7 = 25,
  A9 = 91
} Select;
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"call values"*? Or by *"link one of those values [...] to a number in an Array"*?

Comment: A `typedef` declares an alias for a type.  You then use the defined alias, i.e. `Select`, as a type name anywhere that a type name is expected.  For their part, the enum constants can be used as typed constants, somewhat as if they had been declared as variables of type `const int`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to C, you must first understand what typedef and enums are used for, before figuring out the intention of that enum typedef (which I assume is from some assignment ?). Checkout the answer provided in this post: [How do I use typedef and typedef enum in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426716/how-do-i-use-typedef-and-typedef-enum-in-c)

Coming to your question - " how would I call values from typedef enum, and can I link one of the values in typedef enum to a number in an Array?" - 
The "values" in an enum are actually constants (like Macro definitions). They can be assigned to variables and passed to functions like any constants.

What can you do with a typedef enum, you ask? For one thing, if used properly, it can improve code readability. When you typedef an enum, you are specifying a new data type. Variables declared with this new type, can be expected to take values specified in the enum. Nothing stops these variables from taking other values, but the code becomes more readable, and the intent of the variables is clear to anyone reading the code. It is common to have enums for error codes. So status variables that are declared using such typedef enums can be expected to contain one of the error codes listed in the enum.

If I would hazard a guess, the enum you have specified probably holds indices of interest in an array, or expected values at certain indices in the array. Anyway, if you go through the rest of your code, you will find out your self!