# Can't use typedef enum

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, c++14, android-camera2

I have a header file with definition:

```
typedef enum acamera_metadata_enum_android_lens_facing {
// enumeration
} acamera_metadata_enum_android_lens_facing_t;
```

The problem is when I am trying to declare this enum as my class'es member the compiler can't find definition (header is found).

```
../../../../src/main/cpp/include/camera_manager.h:41:9: error: unknown type name 'acamera_metadata_enum_android_lens_facing_t'
          acamera_metadata_enum_android_lens_facing_t facing;
```

This is my class header:

```
#ifndef DAVINCI_CAMERA_MANAGER_H
#define DAVINCI_CAMERA_MANAGER_H

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <camera/NdkCameraManager.h>
#include <camera/NdkCameraError.h>
#include <camera/NdkCameraDevice.h>
#include <camera/NdkCameraMetadataTags.h> // The enumeration is defined here
#include <media/NdkImageReader.h>

namespace DaVinci {
    class CameraId;

    class CameraManager {
        struct ACameraManager *_manager;
        std::map<std::string, CameraId> _cameras;
        std::string _activeCameraId;

        int32_t _cameraFacing;
        int32_t _cameraOrientation;

        bool _valid;

    public:
        CameraManager();
        ~CameraManager();
    };

    // helper classes to hold enumerated camera
    class CameraId {
    public:
        struct ACameraDevice *device;
        std::string id;
        acamera_metadata_enum_android_lens_facing_t facing;
        bool available;  // free to use ( no other apps are using
        bool owner;      // we are the owner of the camera

        explicit CameraId(const char *id);
        explicit CameraId();
    };
};

#endif //DAVINCI_CAMERA_MANAGER_H
```

Where can the problem be?
**P.S.** I am using c++ 14 if it's important.

**UPDATED**
I created a repository with my project: [https://bitbucket.org/ghostman2013/davinci_test](https://bitbucket.org/ghostman2013/davinci_test/src/master/)

Comment: Looks fine to me from what you've shown. Is your enum defined inside a namespace? Are the include guards in its header correct? As an aside, it's not necessary to typedef enums in C++. That's a C-ism.

Comment: @Fibbles, I can't change built-in system header. It's from Android NDK.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm not familiar with the Android dev kit. If it's definitely defined in that header and you're including that header then it should work. There's nothing wrong with your syntax. It has to be some sort of problem with including the file. If the same header guard is used in another file you may not get the contents of `camera/NdkCameraMetadataTags.h` even if you include it.

Comment: @Fibbles, yap, it is used but all headers have guards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use typedef and typedef enum in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426716/how-do-i-use-typedef-and-typedef-enum-in-c)

Comment: If this part of SDK headers than maybe in order to use it you need to define particular conditional compilation macro?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Did you make sure to set your `minSdkVersion` to 24 or higher?

Comment: @Michael, honestly, I can't get too. I have switched my C++ standard to 11 but it doesn't work still. I've created a repository: [https://bitbucket.org/ghostman2013/davinci_test/src/master/](https://bitbucket.org/ghostman2013/davinci_test/src/master/). Maybe do u be able to get where is my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project's `app/build.gradle` you have `minSdkVersion` set to 21.

The native camera APIs [were added in API level 24](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis).

So you can either A) increase your `minSdkVersion` to 24 or higher, or B) Not use the native camera APIs in your library.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen your comment already. Thank you very much... I even didn't think about SDK version, I don't why but I was sure that the native camera was built in NDK for long time already.